# How to auto snapshot Google cloud platform VM-instances in window server 2018

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup, google-compute-engine, snapshot

For VM-instances with linux which have SSH. I know that can using link as below 
https://github.com/grugnog/google-cloud-auto-snapshot

But for Window Server which is using RDP, How can i do it auto snapshot daily ?
Or i need to using gcloud command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Feb. 14, 2019, Google has finally released in beta scheduled snapshots -

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots

Here's how it looks like in the Google Cloud Console:

[image]

For Windows instances, you must select **Enable VSS.**

*Image taken from [Google Blog.](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/introducing-scheduled-snapshots-for-compute-engine-persistent-disk)*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Windows Instance Snapshots by following the steps attached to the attached article [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot#create-snapshot).

Comment: Improve your answer by including the steps. Include the link as a reference. Links change over time which can break your answer. An answer usually should exist without requiring following a link. There  are exceptions of course. Otherwise your answer should be a comment to the question.

Comment: Does the Step provide auto instance snapshots ?
And will it effect my current data inside my server ?

Comment: If you would like to automate the backups, you will have to create a script using either the api or gcloud commands. From there, you will need to create a cron job using the script if you would like to have it done on a timely basis. Snapshots will not affect the data on the Windows Instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, taking snapshot of any instance is taking snapshot of all the involved disks
And there are commands to take snapshot of any disk in gcp
And you can use Google Cloud scheduler to schedule any jobs/tasks
So using scheduler to automatically take disk snapshots can be used to take snapshot of any instance (including windows)